# Multiple ropes carrying an object

Tags: forces, equilibrium

[image: Tension]

In this problem, the three objects are identical in shape and mass. The suspended horizontal object is uniform and ropes are attached to the object at same distances (the distance between $T_4$ and $T_5$ is the same distance between $T_5$ and $T_6$)

The mass of horizontal suspended object is given.

My question is about the tensions $(T_4 - T_5 - T_6)$, how can I calculate these tensions as it is 2 equations for 3 variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now for simplicity let's assume that the second string is exactly at the middle of the rod and other two strings are placed symmetrically at an distance $ x $ from the centre of the rod at the bottom. Also consider uniform mass distribution of the lower rod . Now my aim is two showcase to you that unless given a initial condition we can't find exact values of $ T_{4} , T_{5} , T_{6}  $ . We could only suggest a triple satisfying our equations .  [image] Now lets begin with our analysis for the lower mass M :-  we can balance the forces in the vertical direction that is ( $ T_{4} + T_{5} + T_{6} = Mg $ ) and two equations for balancing torque on the system that are ( $ ( T₄ - T_{6} ) . x  = 0 $ and  $ T_{5} + 2T _{6} = Mg  $ )  from these  equations we realise that there are three unknowns and only 2 equations ( as all the three equations are not independent )  hence we can  only find a triple  $ ( T₄ , T_{5} , T_{6} ) $  hence if we assume  $ T₄  = T $ then  the triple becomes $ (T , Mg-2T , T) $ from this we can also conclude that the tensions in the above strings are also inderminate . To solve for exact values one needs a initial condition that is independent  of the above equations and unless it is given I am sorry my friend we can't find exact values

Comment: The strings *are* placed symmetrically. The OP says: *"(the distance between T4 and T5 is the same distance between T5 and T6)"*

Comment: Okhh so you want me to remove that line ?

Comment: Okhh thanks for advising from next time I'll be more careful

Comment: @PM2Ring sorry, but i don't get it how we can have a solution if it is a symmetrical ?! 
it still 2 equations for 3 variables

Comment: @PM2Ring because of symmetry we can say that $T_1=T_3$ but $T_2$ can't be equal to $T_1$ or $T_3$ because of the symmetry, as far as i understand

Comment: @Mohamed Anis why?  say  that everything is symmetrical then $ T_{4} =T_{5}=T_{6} = \frac {Mg}{3} $ and hence applying same analysis on m we can get rest tensions equal to $ \frac {(3m+M)g}{3} $

Comment: @Mohamed Anis :- PM2Ring just gave you a initial condition that tensions in all the strings is equal. Forget symmetry as I think you are right the argument of symmetry wouldn't work here. The symmetry PM2Ring talks about is misleading and vague and needs better wording

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that we are considering the objects are perfectly rigid bodies, this system is [Statically indeterminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statically_indeterminate).  This means we have multiple solutions that satisfy the equilibrium, and thus we cannot determine the correct forces this system would experience.

For example, if the beams are perfectly rigid, we could assume that the middle string carries *all* the tension of the bottom piece, *none* of the tension of the bottom piece, or *a third* the tension of the bottom piece, and forces and moments could be balanced regardless.

To get over this, you would need to make some assumption about the system which would allow for a unique solution.  One way this is often done is by removing the assumption that the bodies are rigid, and instead treat them like real materials subject to [deformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_(engineering)).